# Question about unweighted ANES survey in R

Tags: r, survey

This may be more of a statistical question. I am trying wrap my head around understanding unweighted frequencies in R, using the 2016 ANES survey. I downloaded the data using `anesr` and am working with Anthony Damico's textbook on `lodown`: http://asdfree.com/american-national-election-study-anes.html

ANES Guide: https://electionstudies.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/anes_timeseries_2016_userguidecodebook.pdf

ANES is a panel survey, with a pre and post election interview.

Apologies that I cannot post the underlying data. But essentially, I am trying to understand one issue.

Let's say I want to get an unweighted count of responses to V161195x, which summarizes view on what should be done with children brought to the US illegally. Using the unweighted data frame, I run:

```
table(anes_df$V161195x)

Yielding: 
-9   -8    1    2    3    4    5    6 
  47   29  329  332  112  435 1437 1549
```

-9 and -8 are refused to answer or N/A.

I then use the `survey` package to make a complex sample survey design and an easier to read output.

```
anes_design <- 
  svydesign( 
    ~V160202, # full sample weight 
    strata = ~V160201, 
    data = anes_df , 
    weights = ~V160102 , # full sample weight 
    nest = TRUE 
  )
  
anes_design <- 
  update( 
    anes_design,
    
    one = 1, # dummy 1 for each record

    undoc_kids =
      factor(V161195x , levels = 1:6 , labels =
                c( 'should sent back - favor a great deal' ,
                   'should sent back - favor a moderate amount' ,
                   'should sent back - favor a little' ,
                   'should allow to stay - favor a little' ,
                   'should allow to stay - favor a moderate amount' ,
                   'should allow to stay - favor a great deal' )
      )     
  )


svyby( ~ one , ~ undoc_kids , anes_design , unwtd.count )

# yields 
should sent back - favor a great deal                   should sent back - favor a great deal    270  0
should sent back - favor a moderate amount         should sent back - favor a moderate amount    292  0
should sent back - favor a little                           should sent back - favor a little    102  0
should allow to stay - favor a little                   should allow to stay - favor a little    361  0
should allow to stay - favor a moderate amount should allow to stay - favor a moderate amount   1216  0
should allow to stay - favor a great deal           should allow to stay - favor a great deal   1348  0
```

This does not match the output in the first table, even though they are both unweighted. It seems like the svyby function is only including observations that were in both the pre and post election survey, but the question was only in the pre election survey.

When I re run the analysis using `V160101` (pre election only) instead of `V160202` the output matches...so which is best to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the post-election weight variable, which is missing (or possibly zero) for people who aren't in the post-election survey, you will only get observations that are in both surveys.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I gathered. In that case, when doing weighted analyses, I would have to use different weights depending on the question, yes? E.g. the codebook lists a few weights: V160102 for "full sample using post‐election survey only or both pre and post" and V160101 for  "full sample using pre‐election survey data only"